# RuntimeError: numero máximo de chamadas recursivas excedido - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursão, fibonnaci

```
fibonacci_cache = {}
def fibonacci(n):
    if n in fibonacci_cache:
        return fibonacci_cache[n]

    if n==1:
        value=1
    elif n==2:
        value=1
    elif n>2:
        value=fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

fibonacci_cache[n]=value
return value

for n in (1,1000,91723):
    print (n,":",fibonacci(n))
```

Versão do python:Python 2.7.10.

Devolveu-me este erro: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Como faço para resolver este problema?

Comment: O Python, por padrão, permite uma profundidade máxima de 1000 na recursividade. Você realmente precisa calcular para valores tão altos assim ou é um exercício para treino?

Comment: Eu pensava que dava para calcular para todos os números mas fui testar e devolveu isso.Eu quero alterar o código de forma a funcionar para qualquer numero

Comment: Recursivamente não será possível. Sempre haverá valores que estourarão a profundidade máxima da recursividade.

Comment: Como faço para alocar mais recursos para acelerar o calculo da expressão de fibonacci? Tipo o cpu tem quase 85% de inactividade e ele so esta a usar 10% para a execução do código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python, por padrão, permite você possuir uma profundidade máxima igual a 1000 dentro da recursividade; quando este valor é excedido, o erro citado será emitido.

> *RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.*

Você pode verificar o valor exato em seu servidor através da biblioteca `sys`, com a função [`getrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit):

```
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

Você pode, ainda, alterar este valor com a função [`setrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit):

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
```

O valor máximo, conforme a documentação, que você pode definir dependerá das limitações plataforma onde está executando o código; e mesmo que seja um valor muito alto, sempre haverá um valor que excederá a profundidade máxima. Não há como fugir disso com recursividade.

Porém, uma solução bastante simples é calcular a sequência de Fibonacci através de um gerador:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    yield a
    for _ in range(1, n):
        a, b = b, a+b
        yield a
```

Mas como você não tem interesse em obter a sequência propriamente dita, mas sim o *n-ésimo* termo da sequência, podemos gerar um iterador que percorrerá nosso gerador no intervalo que desejamos, isto é, no *n-ésimo* termo. Fazemos isso utilizando a função [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) da biblioteca `itertools`:

```
import itertools

def nth_value(n):
    iterator = itertools.islice(fibonacci(n), n-1, None)
    return next(iterator)
```

Ficando:

```
import itertools

def fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    yield a
    for _ in range(1, n):
        a, b = b, a+b
        yield a

def nth_value(n):
    return next(itertools.islice(fibonacci(n), n-1, n))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/1nMIKU) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NuZ5) | [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1500+th+term+in+fibonacci)</sup>

Comment: Tentei executar isso na minha maquina mas ele demora muito a obter o valor. Não tem forma de diminuir o tempo de execução? no site ele devolve o resultado mais rápido. Se calhar o poder computacional não pode ser equiparado.

Comment: @ManuelJose Sim, esta solução tende a ser muito rápida. Tem certeza que implementou o código corretamente?

Comment: como faço para ver o tempo de execução. Se os tempos de execução forem diferentes no site https://repl.it/NuZ5 e na minha maquina, quer dizer que temos diferentes poderes computacionais, nomeadamente na rapidez em carregar valores da memória ram para o cpu

Comment: @ManuelJose Com o comando `time` no Linux, ou com o módulo `timeit` do Python.

Comment: Na maquina é ligeiramente mais rápido que no site. Mas os valores não são sempre constantes a cada execução

Comment: @ManuelJose Você deve estar fazendo algo errado. Consegue replicar seu código no Repl.it?

Comment: https://repl.it/NuZ5/2

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68350/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-manuel-jose).